# SQL Server 2016 Database Mail will not connect to mail server

Tags: sql-server

I have set up database mail in SQL Server 2016, this server is hosted in the cloud.  I had this working in SQL Server 2016 that is installed on my laptop. I did the exact same set up.

Looked up on web and stack overflow numerous others issues and I have all those setting set.

Database Mail setup

- Email address is an Office 365 active account
- Port 587 with smtp.office365.com
- SSL is checked
- Basic authentication uses the email address and a valid active password

Profile is set up to use this account. Default set to yes.

As mentioned earlier this exact same account works now in SQL Server 2016 on my laptop.

In database email log, I see these messages:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2019-07-30T08:37:00).
>
> Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 52.96.79.18:587). Sending Mail using Account 1 (2019-07-30T08:38:37).
>
> Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 52.96.73.50:587). \

I have looked up tons of peoples issues and I have all those steps completed.

I use Office 365 as my email server.

I can ping Office 365 on the server.

Firewall is not blocking it.

I look on Exchange server on O365 and email is not getting there at all.

No AV on this server blocking it.

Spam filter in front of O365 is not blocking it.

Database mail is running on SQL Server.

It appears to me it is never leaving the server for some reason.  I send test email and it sits for a like 2-3 minutes then fails.  Whereas on my laptop SQL it goes in like 1 second and email is in my inbox.

[image]

[Scripts results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujPxR.png)

Comment: Run these scripts on your server and see what gets returned.
`EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_account_sp;`
`EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_profile_sp;`
`EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_profileaccount_sp;`
`EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_principalprofile_sp`;

Comment: @WEI_DBA  I could not figure out how to add results to this comment so I edited my post and attached the results there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state: this server is hosted in the cloud... where in the cloud: AWS, Azure? If AWS, is it an RDS or EC2? Sounds to me like the message is being blocked possibly the outgoing port by the cloud provider. For instance, AWS throttles sending email over port 25 by default last time I checked.

If it is AWS, then perhaps this would help? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/

Comment: That’s a good idea.  It is not aws or azure.   Private vendor.  But let me check that out.  That is a difference between my laptop version and thus server.   Will report back.

Comment: this was the right answer.   I have server cloud by private hosting company.  But I had to ask them to allow me to send email.

Comment: Glad my advice helped! You could indicate a correct answer by clicking the check mark next to it. :)